# How to Run iPython (and Jupyter notebook) for Python3.6.0 on Windows?

Tags: python, cmd, path, ipython, python-3.6

Just recently, I figured that I need to install the latest version of python (python 3.6.0) because it has pretty much all the dependencies to run the scikit-learn package with no issues.

I am a fan of ipython, and I use it frequently to run scripts on the previous version of python that I had (python 2.7).  The problem is that I am not able to run ipython for the latest version of python that I have just installed (python 3.6.0).

**Question:**  What are the possible ways that I should do to make the ipython switch to the latest version of python I have installed in my machine (python 3.6.0)?

**Some description that might be helpful:**

-I use Cygwin to run Unix-like command on the Windows command prompt (cmd.exe)
-I have successfully installed ipython using `pip3 install ipython`

```
    C:\Users\MyComputer>pip3 install ipython
    Collecting ipython
    Downloading ipython-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (747kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 747kB 683kB/s
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably have to install `jupyter` -> `pip3 install jupyter`. Then, start the notebook server with `jupyter notebook`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too. I did it by

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 myenv
# activate myenv as described here
# https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/
pip install ipython
ipython
```

I also found this worked

```
pip3 install ipython
FULL_PATH_TO/python3.6 FULL_PATH_TO/ipython
```